# ubuntu: mumble 1.2.2 in Karmic

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, package-management, mumble

Karmic only has mumble 1.1.8, but if I want to connect to a 1.2 server I need to upgrade... So I would like to know how I can upgrade to mumble 1.2.2 **without messing myself up for later when I upgrade to 10.04 and beyond... I just want a smooth transition into the next versions of mumble**.

Is there anyway to upgrade to this newer version and either keep it in the package manager or make it not interfere with the natural upgrades the program will later recieve from the package manager?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to find an alternate maintainer of this package an use that.  The closest I could find was [GetDeb 1.2.0-1](http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/apps/m/mumble/mumble_1.2.0-1~getdeb1_i386.deb) and [1.2.2-1~ppa1~karmic1](https://launchpad.net/~slicer/+archive/ppa) created by [Thorval Natvig](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ThorvaldNatvig), the Ubuntu maintainer of the mumble package.  The only problem is that mumble has [a lot of dependencies](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/mumble/1.1.8-3), so you may need other version of dependent packages, not just this one.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd be able to find an updated *mumble* package in the Karmic backports repository, but it doesn't appear that one currently exists.  Once a package is backported, most required dependencies are also backported (or the backport is configured to work with packages from the standard Karmic repositories).

[DaveParillo's PPA suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/130730/ubuntu-mumble-1-2-2-in-karmic/130736#130736) would be my second-preferred option.

A third option is grabbing the source package of [Lucid's *mumble* package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/mumble) (or alternately from Debian's [unstable](http://packages.debian.org/sid/mumble) or [testing](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/mumble) repositories) and [building a local package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) ([related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source)) on your Karmic system.

Finally, you could compile and install your own version to /usr/local or /opt.  This is out of control of the package manager, but the package manager won't install anything to these locations so it's not impossible to remove those files after upgrading to Lucid.